# Sound not working after a few minutes

Tags: windows-7, audio, video, skype, headset

I've been having this error recently and I thought it was due to Skype since when I had Skype open I couldn't hear sound. After the call I had to reboot to get sound.

Then I was just watching a youtube video when the sound suddenly stopped halfway through the video. My mixer bar still said that sound was being received from the video. anyway here are some things about the computer

Mx 17 Windows 7 alienware, I use the headset that came with the computer. It recently had all of its data erased due to a virus that was hidden where my security systems couldn't detect It.

Comment: what browser are you using? any plugins/extensions? Do you have a sound card? What audio drivers are you using

Comment: Did you find a solution? Having a similar issue with sound.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the virus may have replaced/corrupted some files related to your sound driver. I would attempt to re-install the sound driver and any software that came with it.